# Using atom as in-memory database in ring website

Tags: database, multithreading, clojure, ring

I'm trying to build a very simple wiki-like system in Clojure and serving the http using Ring.

Instead of using a regular database i was thinking about using just an atom and serialise it to a file when it gets changed. Something like https://github.com/alandipert/enduro just with a delayed write.

Having the data in-mem in vectors and maps will surely make the service faster and the code simpler/more intuitive to write?

Will that work with a multithreaded Jetty/Ring server?

The content of the atom will surely fit in memory for now, but that might not hold true in the future. Any ideas to how i can structure the code to make it easier to switch to an alternative storage backend in the future?

Comment: My first thought would be an Entry interface with set!/get! operations that conditionally returns another Entry interface as sub-entry. You could later change the implementation, even sub-entry specific. Whether it "works" multithreaded would depened on what synchronization constraints operations with multiple reads and writes require and which of them could perform in parallel.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. You'll end up rewriting a lot of database functionality. If you want something simple consider starting an embedded elasticsearch node (in the same JVM, super simple, 2 LOC) which would also be fantastic for full text search. And elastisch (clojure client) is super easy. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best guide for keeping data in memory and storing it to a single file: http://www.brandonbloom.name/blog/2013/06/26/slurp-and-spit/

Answer (score 1):

[Datomic](http://docs.datomic.com/getting-started.html) would give you a few options.

You could use the in-memory db which would give you query power and thread safety. It would also be very easy to switch to a persistent datastore if/when the time comes. However, I'm not sure about serialization of the in-memory db.

Or you could use Datomic just for Datalog, which can be used for querying data structures. In that case, you could use an atom and then serialize as planned. Moving to a persistent datastore would be more work than the first case, but still not much. In either case, most of your code wouldn't need to change.

In my opinion, you'd be better of just starting with the free version of Datomic that uses the file system as a datastore. I don't think using an atom simplifies your code very much.

Answer (score 1):

I second the recommendation for Datomic.

I've been using it on a "real" project for a few weeks now, and the more I use it, the more I realize that it would be a solid foundation for handling your data in any non-trivial project.  Even if you never plan to use a "real" database in the future, just having a fact-based data model, powerful querying, and even full-text search built in is a huge win over just using an atom to store some huge map.

I checked and the free version does give you local storage as well as the in-memory database, so that would solve your storage needs perfectly (it uses an H2 database behind the scenes).  And if you ever find yourself needing to scale to something bigger, you're already set.